# How do I get this loop to output the correct things?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

std::string text = "dnoiwnenfsldhatnjffat";
std::string stuff[] = { "hat", "fat", "hoe"};
for (auto item : stuff) {
    std::size_t n = item.find(text);
    if (n != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "Found at position " << n << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
  }
}
```

What I want it to do is to get the output

```
hat found
cat found
hoe not found
```

Ok this has been answered. Thanks for all the help. This is to find certain words from an array inside a string.

Comment: Modify your shown code so that there's no file operations, and your `text` and `animals` are hard coded. This will let us see the operation much easier. `text = "bat ant robin"; animals = {"bat", "ant", "robin", "penguin", "cat", "vulture"};` or whatever your actual inputs are. Then let us know what your observed output is and what you expected output is. This is known as a [example].

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice yeah i understand but this is my first time using c++. I wasn't getting an error while trying to do what i wanted to do it just ran but i can't get it to actually do what i want it to do if that makes sense? It runs and the program doesn't identify any errors but i can't get it to output which of the words in the array are not in the string

Comment: This shouldn't compile as is. You have two variables named `animals`. You can set a `std::vector<std::string>` using this notation `std::vector<std::string> animals = {"dog", "cat", "cow", "pig", "fox"};` make sure your example that you post here compiles.

Comment: Also "error" is contextual. It can mean a compilation error, but it can also mean a functional error, where code compiles but doesn't match our desired requirements.

Comment: And after you modify your program above so that it compiles, make ANOTHER code box with the *exact* output you see and the *exact* output you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice john it means a lot. I edited the code and it does compile now thanks to your help. Now could i please get some help with getting the code to also out which animals in the array were not found in the string?

Comment: I think an array would have been fine.  The only reason to use a vector is if the array is going to change in size or you don't know how big it will be.  People suggesting vectors are just doing that because it is good advice for the future - it isn't actually helping solve your problem.

Comment: @Jerry the code originally had a `vector` because it was taking inputs from a file and getting them `push_back`d into it.

Comment: You mind showing Jerry? Sorry for my incompetence it's just that i am completely clueless with this right now. Just started using it last night and the code that i came up with comes from bits and bobs of research i did on the internet

Comment: yeah jerry the original code had push_back on it.

Comment: @cheesy it looks like you want your loop to output which `animal`s are not in the `string`. Is it okay to interleave the output? "dog is in the file, cat is not in the file, cow is in the file", or do you want to list all the ones in the file followed by all the ones not in the file.

Comment: If you edit your question to show *exactly* how you want your output to look, we can better help you. Right now I have to keep asking questions. There are different approaches depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Sure thing John, i hope i made clear now what i need this program to output.

Comment: 'dog' is not in your input string. But you say you want your output to report it found. Please type out the *exact* output you want to see given this program shown.

Comment: ok done. That's exactly the output i need from this. I just need the program to be able to produce this output. It's not the exact output i'm looking for in my original program but if this program is able to give this output, then it should be able to give the correct output for my original program

Comment: So you want the found animals to be output in order that they appear in your search string. What determines the order of output for the animals NOT found in the search string?

Comment: Actually the order of the output is not important. What i need is for it to actually output the NOT found animals aswel as the found. That's all. The order doesn't matter

Comment: I think I'll be able to fix it, but it's not my job to fix it, it's yours. I'll give you some tips in an answer hang on.

Comment: Actually, are you allowed to use `std::string::find`? Or have you been expressly forbidden from using it? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: This current incarnation of the code searches for `text` in each `item`. How many times does `"twpignhcatkdcowd"` appear in `"pig"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to use `std::string::find`. To find a given string `search` in another given string `text`, you do this:

```
std::size_t n = text.find(search);
if (n != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "Found at position " << n << "\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the help. I tried this code but it doesn't compile. Where exactly should i put it? After the variables are declared or do i need something else?

Comment: Well of course it doesn't compile by itself. This is for finding a given string `search` in another given string `text`. So you'd replace the part of your code that does searching with something that looks like this. Replace `search` and `text` with your variables.

Comment: Oh my bad, you can't put a declaration in an if statement apparently. Let me edit that.

Comment: I edited the question to what my code is now but the output is now 'not found' 5 times. I've clearly done something wrong but can't figure it out. I'm really sorry for my incompetence and really thankful for your help

Comment: Oh nvm. I made a couple changes and now it works perfectly! Thank you very much john i really appreciate the help x

Comment: Whenever you use a standard container (like `string` or `vector`), read the full documentation to see what functions are available to you. There's no need for you to build a new car every time you want to go to the grocery store, and there should be no need for you to rewrite simple algorithms that already have implementations (unless of course the point is to learn those algorithms). https://en.cppreference.com